Python: swap position of vars expansion
My function receives object myenum which can be either set or dict.
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
or
{'a': 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 8}
It represents enum like in C/C++.
In case of dict I need enumerate over .items() in case of set I need use enumerate(myenum) like this
for k, i in myenum.items():

for i, k in enumerate(myenum):

I could use ternary itr = myenum.items() if hasattr(myenum, 'keys') else enumerate(myenum)
And then simply have single for.
Unfortunately .items() expands into key, value and enumerate() expands into index, key. index is actually the desired value for the enum.
Is there way to swap places in the expansion? So that enumerate() also expands into key, index?
Right now I have naive solution of 2 for cycles that are identical, just the order of k, i is different, which is ugly.

Don't check if an object is of a given type using hasattr, use isinstance instead.

Are you using the values in your for loop in the case of a dict? It would help if you showed more of the code in the loops

This is a case where the caller, not your function, should be responsible for constructing an appropriate Iterable[str, int] value from whatever set, dict, etc they have.

@matszwecja Python is duck-typing language, there are endless topics proving that usage of isinstance is worse approach. If object is iterable and has keys - for me it is dict even if it is not derived from dict. Tomorrow this function will also receive list and your code will break, while mine will be still fine


Is there way to swap places in the expansion? So that enumerate() also expands into key, index?

If you only need to swap them, this should behave exactly like enumerate other than the swapped items.
def swap_enumerate(enum):
    return ((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(enum))


Although I like the solution from @Guy better, but this answers to my exact question, so accepting this one. Thanks!

You can zip the set with range and convert it to a dict
def func(myenum):
    if isinstance(myenum, set):
        myenum = dict(zip(myenum, range(len(myenum))))

    for k, i in myenum.items():
        print(k, i)


Have to admit, this is an elegant alternative to my issue and I like it. Unfortunately the other answer from fsimonjetz is more on the topic for the question, so had to accept that one. Still, thank you very much!
One note though. Since Python is duck-typing, checking for isinstance is less favorable. But that's minor

I would fix the set into a dict if applicable. Then, I'd only deal with a dict.
def f( myenum ):
    if isinstance(myenum, set):
        myenum = { v : k for k, v in enumerate(myenum) }
    
    for key, value in myenum.items():
        ...


Decompose your function into two simpler functions: one converts a set or dict into an appropriate iterable, and the other uses the iterable.
from typing import Iterable, TypeVar

K = TypeVar('K')

def convert(c: dict[K, int] | set[K]) -> Iterable[tuple[K, int]]:
    if isinstance(c, dict):
        return c.items()
    else:
        return ((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(c))

def process(pairs: Iterable[K, int]):
    for k, i in pairs:
        ...

def func(c: dict[K, int] | set[K]):
    process(convert(c))

You may consider only implementing process, and leaving convert to be implemented by whoever wants to use process.
